# Android Vision API sample app not working on nexus 4, android 5.1.1, and google play services 8.1.15

Tags: android

I am currently exploring Android Vision APIs and trying to test sample 'Barcode Reader' app on my phone (nexus 4 -android 5.1.1 and google play services 8.1.15 ). I keep getting following messages in the log cat. The app doesn't crash on my phone but the barcode detection is not working either. I have taken sample code from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision. I also checked for available space on the phone and it shows 1.73 GB available space. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
I/GMPM﹕ App measurement is starting up
E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
I/Vision﹕ Supported ABIS: [armeabi-v7a, armeabi]
I/Vision﹕ Requesting barcode detector download.
W/Barcode-reader﹕ Detector dependencies are not yet available.
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleared play services cache and data, and then restarted my phone. The sample app is working now.